How can I align these numbers in Custom Tkinter
Whenever I run my code everything is lined up
Output (in vscode / terminal):
Preview 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  R   H   E  
Astros  0                  0   0   0  
Cubs    0                  0   0   0  

But when ever I run my code in CTk the Runs, Hits and, Error numbers don't line up anymore:
Preview 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  R   H   E  
Astros  0           0   0   0  
Cubs    0            0   0   0  

(recreation as when I copy and paste from the textbox it is lined up normally)
vvv CTk Code vvv
import customtkinter
import statsapi
import datetime
import time
import os
    
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
astros_schedule = statsapi.schedule(team=117,start_date=date,end_date=date)
gamepk = astros_schedule[0]['game_id']
astros_linescore = statsapi.linescore(gamePk=gamepk)

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")


app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("Astros Score Manual")
app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.geometry("650,325")
switch_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="off")
def switch_event():
    onoff = switch_var.get()
    if onoff == "off":
        Textbox.delete("0.0","end")
    elif onoff == "on":
        Textbox.configure(state="normal")
        Textbox.insert("0.0", astros_linescore)
        Textbox.configure(state="disabled")






Switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=app, text="CTkSwitch", command=switch_event,
                                   variable=switch_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
Switch.pack(padx=20, pady=10)

Textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master=app,width=675,height=325, corner_radius=20, border_width=5, activate_scrollbars = False, state="disabled",font=("sans-serif",14), wrap="none")
Textbox.pack(padx=20, pady=10)





app.mainloop()

Sorry if this is long winded or confusing this is my first time asking a question.
Ive tried fiddling with the font settings and nothing change

you may have to use some monospace font

@furas thank you this worked changing it to Courier although it is quite bad looking in the text box, if you want can you post your comment as an answer so i can mark it

You have to use some monospace font which has all chars with the same width.
Wikipedia: List of monospaced typefaces - Wikipedia

Minimal working code with some monospace fonts.
import customtkinter

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("650x325")

for font_name in ('monospace', 'Courier', 'Ubuntu Mono'):

    textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(app, font=(font_name, 14), height=100)
    textbox.pack(fill="both", pady=5)

    textbox.insert("end", f"""FONT: {font_name}
    Preview 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  R   H   E  
    Astros  0                  0   0   0  
    Cubs    0                  0   0   0""")

app.mainloop()



EDIT:
Using tkinter.Text you can use tags to format text in one widgets
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("650x325")

textbox = tk.Text(app, height=300)
textbox.pack(fill="both")

for font_name in ('monospace', 'Courier', 'Ubuntu Mono'):

    textbox.insert("end", f"""FONT: {font_name}
    Preview 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  R   H   E  
    Astros  0                  0   0   0  
    Cubs    0                  0   0   0
    
""", font_name)

    textbox.tag_config(font_name, font=(font_name, 14))

app.mainloop()


